Determine the function $f'(x)$ and calculate the limit of $\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{4}\pi}\frac{\cos{x}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}}{x-\frac{1}{4}\pi}$.
The problem:
Regard the limit
$$\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{4}\pi}\frac{\cos{x}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}}{x-\frac{1}{4}\pi}$$
as the derivative in $x=\frac{1}{4}\pi$ to a function $f(x)$. Determine the function $f'(x)$ and calculate the limit.
The original problem in Swedish:
Betrakta
$$\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{4}\pi}\frac{\cos{x}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}}{x-\frac{1}{4}\pi}$$
Se gränsvärdet som derivata i $x=\frac{1}{4}\pi$ till en funktion $f(x)$. Bestäm funktionen $f'(x)$ och beräkna gränsvärdet.
The solution:
$\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{4}\pi}\frac{\cos{x}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}}{x-\frac{1}{4}\pi}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
$f'(x) = -\sin(x)$
The answers I got:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\cos{x}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}}{x-\frac{1}{4}\pi}=\frac{4((\pi-4x)\sin{x}-4\cos{x}+2\sqrt{2})}{(4x-\pi)^2}$$
$$\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{4}\pi}\frac{\cos{x}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}}{x-\frac{1}{4}\pi}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
My question:
Now, I get the right answer for the limit but not the derivative. Doesn't "determine the function $f'(x)$" mean that you gotta differentiate $\frac{\cos{x}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}}{x-\frac{1}{4}\pi}$? Am I to find out something else or have I perhaps differentiated wrong?

Read more carefully the first sentence, to determine the function $f$ which the second sentence asks you to differentiate.

If you let $f(x) = \cos(x)$, the proposed limit can be written as:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\pi/4}\frac{\cos(x) - \sqrt{2}/2}{x - \pi/4} = \lim_{x\to\pi/4}\frac{\cos(x) - \cos(\pi/4)}{x - \pi/4} = \lim_{x\to\pi/4}\frac{f(x) - f(\pi/4)}{x - \pi/4} = f'(\pi/4)
\end{align*}
Since $f'(x) = -\sin(x)$, one may claim that $f'(\pi/4) = -\sin(\pi/4)$.
Hopefully this helps!

How come we do not differentiate the whole rational function but only $\cos{x}$?

@Sien sorry, I did not understand what you meant to say. Could you please rephrase it?

No worries, and thank you for the explanation. You differentiate $\cos{x}$ and not $\frac{\cos{x}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}}{x-\frac{1}{4}\pi}$, why is that? Is there a rule that I am unaware of?

@Sien I applied the definition of derivative.

No.  To apply L'Hopital's rule against $\displaystyle ~\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)},~$ where $~f(a) = 0 = g(a),~$ you must compute $$\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)},$$ evaluated at $~x = a ~$ (or as $~x~$ approaches $~a$). This is distinct from $$\frac{d}{dx} \left[ ~\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} ~\right]$$ evaluated at $~x = a.$
